# How to use class selector with find as javascript only?

Tags: javascript

I got the following jQuery code, which I need to convert to pure javascript:

```
$('.your-name input').val(lastName);
```

While I can use `document.getElementsByClassName("your-name")` I do not know how find the nested input and apply `lastName` to it. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` return something called HTMLCollection - so you have to iterate over each item, but before that you have to convert it into the array using Array.from(prop), because you can't iterate over HTML Colletion, and then assign .value for each item.Or use querySelector, or querySelectorAll which would return something similar called NodeList

Answer (score 2):

you can use querySelectorAll, that does the same as jQuery but in native, or the olfashion way, maybe better in term of performance :

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('your-name')).forEach(function(el) {
  Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = lastName
  })
})
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.querySelector('.your-name input').value=lastName;`

Answer (score -2):

$("input[name='input_name']").val();

this will get the value of your input..